# How to invoke Action<> modifying winforms control

Tags: c#, delegates

I have the following function

```
    private void UnsubscribeSubscribe(Action action)
    {
        action.BeginInvoke(action.EndInvoke, null);
    }
```

Whenever I pass in an action that modifies my controls data source nothing happens. I know the action is being invoked because the query I'm running is returning results. I was reading that you can only modify winform controls from the same thread that added them. How can I make this work?

For example, running 
UnsubscribeSubscribe(() => { Foobar.DataSource = GetResults() });

`GetResults()` will run properly but the data source will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to invoke the delegate on the thread that created the control's underlying handle. [Control.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx) is used for just that.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong method.  A delegate's BeginInvoke() method always runs the delegate target on a threadpool thread.  Poison to the user interface.  You need to use Control.BeginInvoke().  Like the form's BeginInvoke method.  While similarly named, it has *nothing* to do with a delegate's BeginInvoke() method.   For one, you don't have to (and shouldn't) call EndInvoke().

Answer (score 2):

if you need to make an action on a UI thread from the different thread then GUI thread then you should use `Invoke` method like this (this example is for text box - from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)):

```
private void SetText(string text)
{
   // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
   // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
   // If these threads are different, it returns true.
  if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
  { 
    SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
    this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
  }
  else
  {
    this.textBox1.Text = text;
  }
}
```

There is also another approach using [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) class - you can read about using it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/SyncContextTutorial.aspx)